# Understanding PyTorch einsum

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor, numpy-einsum

I'm familiar with how [**`einsum`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) works in NumPy. A similar functionality is also offered by PyTorch: [**torch.einsum()**](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.einsum). What are the similarities and differences, either in terms of functionality or performance? The information available at PyTorch documentation is rather scanty and doesn't provide any insights regarding this.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Since the description of einsum is skimpy in torch documentation, I decided to write this post to document, compare and contrast how [`torch.einsum()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/functional.html#einsum) behaves when compared to [`numpy.einsum()`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html).

**Differences:**

- NumPy allows both small case and capitalized letters `[a-zA-Z]` for the "*subscript string*" whereas PyTorch allows only the small case letters `[a-z]`.
- NumPy accepts nd-arrays, plain Python lists (or tuples), list of lists (or tuple of tuples, list of tuples, tuple of lists) or even PyTorch tensors as *operands* (i.e. inputs). This is because the *operands* have only to be *array_like* and not strictly NumPy nd-arrays. On the contrary, PyTorch expects the *operands* (i.e. inputs) strictly to be PyTorch tensors. It will throw a `TypeError` if you pass either plain Python lists/tuples (or its combinations) or NumPy nd-arrays.
- NumPy supports lot of keyword arguments (for e.g. `optimize`) in addition to `nd-arrays` while PyTorch doesn't offer such flexibility yet.

Here are the implementations of some examples both in PyTorch and NumPy:

```
# input tensors to work with

In [16]: vec
Out[16]: tensor([0, 1, 2, 3])

In [17]: aten
Out[17]: 
tensor([[11, 12, 13, 14],
        [21, 22, 23, 24],
        [31, 32, 33, 34],
        [41, 42, 43, 44]])

In [18]: bten
Out[18]: 
tensor([[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 4]])
```

---

**1) Matrix multiplication**
     PyTorch: `torch.matmul(aten, bten)` ; `aten.mm(bten)`
     NumPy : `np.einsum("ij, jk -> ik", arr1, arr2)`

```
In [19]: torch.einsum('ij, jk -> ik', aten, bten)
Out[19]: 
tensor([[130, 130, 130, 130],
        [230, 230, 230, 230],
        [330, 330, 330, 330],
        [430, 430, 430, 430]])
```

**2) Extract elements along the main-diagonal**
   PyTorch: `torch.diag(aten)`
   NumPy : `np.einsum("ii -> i", arr)`

```
In [28]: torch.einsum('ii -> i', aten)
Out[28]: tensor([11, 22, 33, 44])
```

**3) Hadamard product (i.e. element-wise product of two tensors)**
   PyTorch: `aten * bten`
   NumPy : `np.einsum("ij, ij -> ij", arr1, arr2)`

```
In [34]: torch.einsum('ij, ij -> ij', aten, bten)
Out[34]: 
tensor([[ 11,  12,  13,  14],
        [ 42,  44,  46,  48],
        [ 93,  96,  99, 102],
        [164, 168, 172, 176]])
```

**4) Element-wise squaring**
   PyTorch: `aten ** 2`
   NumPy : `np.einsum("ij, ij -> ij", arr, arr)`

```
In [37]: torch.einsum('ij, ij -> ij', aten, aten)
Out[37]: 
tensor([[ 121,  144,  169,  196],
        [ 441,  484,  529,  576],
        [ 961, 1024, 1089, 1156],
        [1681, 1764, 1849, 1936]])
```

***General***: Element-wise `nth` power can be implemented by repeating the subscript string and tensor `n` times.
For e.g., computing element-wise 4th power of a tensor can be done using:

```
# NumPy: np.einsum('ij, ij, ij, ij -> ij', arr, arr, arr, arr)
In [38]: torch.einsum('ij, ij, ij, ij -> ij', aten, aten, aten, aten)
Out[38]: 
tensor([[  14641,   20736,   28561,   38416],
        [ 194481,  234256,  279841,  331776],
        [ 923521, 1048576, 1185921, 1336336],
        [2825761, 3111696, 3418801, 3748096]])
```

**5) Trace (i.e. sum of main-diagonal elements)**
   PyTorch: `torch.trace(aten)`
   NumPy einsum: `np.einsum("ii -> ", arr)`

```
In [44]: torch.einsum('ii -> ', aten)
Out[44]: tensor(110)
```

**6) Matrix transpose**
   PyTorch: `torch.transpose(aten, 1, 0)`
   NumPy einsum: `np.einsum("ij -> ji", arr)`

```
In [58]: torch.einsum('ij -> ji', aten)
Out[58]: 
tensor([[11, 21, 31, 41],
        [12, 22, 32, 42],
        [13, 23, 33, 43],
        [14, 24, 34, 44]])
```

**7) Outer Product (of vectors)**
   PyTorch: `torch.ger(vec, vec)`
   NumPy einsum: `np.einsum("i, j -> ij", vec, vec)`

```
In [73]: torch.einsum('i, j -> ij', vec, vec)
Out[73]: 
tensor([[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 2, 4, 6],
        [0, 3, 6, 9]])
```

**8) Inner Product (of vectors)**
   PyTorch: `torch.dot(vec1, vec2)`
   NumPy einsum: `np.einsum("i, i -> ", vec1, vec2)`

```
In [76]: torch.einsum('i, i -> ', vec, vec)
Out[76]: tensor(14)
```

**9) Sum along axis 0**
   PyTorch: `torch.sum(aten, 0)`
   NumPy einsum: `np.einsum("ij -> j", arr)`

```
In [85]: torch.einsum('ij -> j', aten)
Out[85]: tensor([104, 108, 112, 116])
```

**10) Sum along axis 1**
    PyTorch: `torch.sum(aten, 1)`
    NumPy einsum: `np.einsum("ij -> i", arr)`

```
In [86]: torch.einsum('ij -> i', aten)
Out[86]: tensor([ 50,  90, 130, 170])
```

**11) Batch Matrix Multiplication**
    PyTorch: `torch.bmm(batch_tensor_1, batch_tensor_2)`
    NumPy  : `np.einsum("bij, bjk -> bik", batch_tensor_1, batch_tensor_2)`

```
# input batch tensors to work with
In [13]: batch_tensor_1 = torch.arange(2 * 4 * 3).reshape(2, 4, 3)
In [14]: batch_tensor_2 = torch.arange(2 * 3 * 4).reshape(2, 3, 4) 

In [15]: torch.bmm(batch_tensor_1, batch_tensor_2)  
Out[15]: 
tensor([[[  20,   23,   26,   29],
         [  56,   68,   80,   92],
         [  92,  113,  134,  155],
         [ 128,  158,  188,  218]],

        [[ 632,  671,  710,  749],
         [ 776,  824,  872,  920],
         [ 920,  977, 1034, 1091],
         [1064, 1130, 1196, 1262]]])

# sanity check with the shapes
In [16]: torch.bmm(batch_tensor_1, batch_tensor_2).shape 
Out[16]: torch.Size([2, 4, 4])

# batch matrix multiply using einsum
In [17]: torch.einsum("bij, bjk -> bik", batch_tensor_1, batch_tensor_2)
Out[17]: 
tensor([[[  20,   23,   26,   29],
         [  56,   68,   80,   92],
         [  92,  113,  134,  155],
         [ 128,  158,  188,  218]],

        [[ 632,  671,  710,  749],
         [ 776,  824,  872,  920],
         [ 920,  977, 1034, 1091],
         [1064, 1130, 1196, 1262]]])

# sanity check with the shapes
In [18]: torch.einsum("bij, bjk -> bik", batch_tensor_1, batch_tensor_2).shape
```

**12) Sum along axis 2**
    PyTorch: `torch.sum(batch_ten, 2)`
    NumPy einsum: `np.einsum("ijk -> ij", arr3D)`

```
In [99]: torch.einsum("ijk -> ij", batch_ten)
Out[99]: 
tensor([[ 50,  90, 130, 170],
        [  4,   8,  12,  16]])
```

**13) Sum all the elements in an nD tensor**
    PyTorch: `torch.sum(batch_ten)`
    NumPy einsum: `np.einsum("ijk -> ", arr3D)`

```
In [101]: torch.einsum("ijk -> ", batch_ten)
Out[101]: tensor(480)
```

**14) Sum over multiple axes (i.e. marginalization)**
    PyTorch: `torch.sum(arr, dim=(dim0, dim1, dim2, dim3, dim4, dim6, dim7))`
    NumPy: `np.einsum("ijklmnop -> n", nDarr)`

```
# 8D tensor
In [103]: nDten = torch.randn((3,5,4,6,8,2,7,9))
In [104]: nDten.shape
Out[104]: torch.Size([3, 5, 4, 6, 8, 2, 7, 9])

# marginalize out dimension 5 (i.e. "n" here)
In [111]: esum = torch.einsum("ijklmnop -> n", nDten)
In [112]: esum
Out[112]: tensor([  98.6921, -206.0575])

# marginalize out axis 5 (i.e. sum over rest of the axes)
In [113]: tsum = torch.sum(nDten, dim=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7))

In [115]: torch.allclose(tsum, esum)
Out[115]: True
```

**15) Double Dot Products / [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product) (same as: torch.sum(hadamard-product) cf. 3)**
    PyTorch: `torch.sum(aten * bten)`
    NumPy  : `np.einsum("ij, ij -> ", arr1, arr2)`

```
In [120]: torch.einsum("ij, ij -> ", aten, bten)
Out[120]: tensor(1300)
```

Comment: @FredGuth yes! I've now updated with a clear example, just not to confuse with the shapes. It's exactly like a matrix multiplication but the batch dimension just hangs around for the ride..

Comment: A difference from numpy docs: "If a label appears only once, it is not summed" i.e. "np.einsum('i', a) produces a view of a with no changes" but "torch.einsum('i', a)" is not valid.

Comment: @dashesy I think it's correct to say that both numpy and torch behaves similarly when we don't do any operation on the input array/tensor resp. For example: with `t = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])` as input, the result of `torch.einsum('...', t)` would return the input tensor. Analogously, in NumPy, with `tn = t.numpy()` as input, the result of `np.einsum('...', tn)` would also return the same input array as a *view*. So, I don't see any difference here. Am I missing something else? Could you please give an example of the case that you had in mind? (i.e. the one that threw an error)  :)

Comment: it seems numpy [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) is not correct `np.einsum('i', a)` mentioned there is invalid even in numpy.

Answer (score 0):

The current answer seems to be outdated now, because of some inaccuracies about `torch.einsum` (the examples are the same):

1. You can use both lower and upper case letters
2. Remains the same (by design)
3. No `optimize` keyword argument exists because it already uses an optimized order for Tensor Network Contraction. Also, the other keywords for `np.einsum` relate to the output `[out, dtype, order, casting]`.

There is a note worth reading about the optimal contraction order in the [`torch.einsum` docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html), which also shows how to disable the optimized order if you want to.

**Extra: Sublist notation**

Since the time of this post both `np` and `torch` have added support for the sublist notation:
(example from pytorch docs)

```py
>>> # with sublist format and ellipsis
>>> torch.einsum(As, [..., 0, 1], Bs, [..., 1, 2], [..., 0, 2])
tensor([[[-1.0564, -1.5904,  3.2023,  3.1271],
        [-1.6706, -0.8097, -0.8025, -2.1183]],

        [[ 4.2239,  0.3107, -0.5756, -0.2354],
        [-1.4558, -0.3460,  1.5087, -0.8530]],

        [[ 2.8153,  1.8787, -4.3839, -1.2112],
        [ 0.3728, -2.1131,  0.0921,  0.8305]]])
```

This example also makes use of the ellipsis `...`, which represents all dimensions not required as a subscript (this is mentioned in a comment of the answer but not explained). Refer to the torch docs again for an in-depth explanation of how that works.