# Understanding Jacobian tensor gradients in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient, tensor

I was going through [official pytorch tut](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/autogradqs_tutorial.html#optional-reading-tensor-gradients-and-jacobian-products), where it explains tensor gradients and Jacobian products as follows:

> Instead of computing the Jacobian matrix itself, PyTorch allows you to compute Jacobian Product  for a given input vector v=(v1…vm). This is achieved by calling backward with v as an argument:

```
inp = torch.eye(5, requires_grad=True)
out = (inp+1).pow(2)
out.backward(torch.ones_like(inp), retain_graph=True)
print("First call\n", inp.grad)
out.backward(torch.ones_like(inp), retain_graph=True)
print("\nSecond call\n", inp.grad)
inp.grad.zero_()
out.backward(torch.ones_like(inp), retain_graph=True)
print("\nCall after zeroing gradients\n", inp.grad)
```

Ouptut:

```
First call
 tensor([[4., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [2., 4., 2., 2., 2.],
        [2., 2., 4., 2., 2.],
        [2., 2., 2., 4., 2.],
        [2., 2., 2., 2., 4.]])

Second call
 tensor([[8., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
        [4., 8., 4., 4., 4.],
        [4., 4., 8., 4., 4.],
        [4., 4., 4., 8., 4.],
        [4., 4., 4., 4., 8.]])

Call after zeroing gradients
 tensor([[4., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [2., 4., 2., 2., 2.],
        [2., 2., 4., 2., 2.],
        [2., 2., 2., 4., 2.],
        [2., 2., 2., 2., 4.]])
```

Though I get what is Jacobian matrix is, I didnt get how is this Jacobian product is calculated.

Here, are different tensors I tried to print out to get understanding:

```
>>> out
tensor([[4., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 4., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 4., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 4., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 4.]], grad_fn=<PowBackward0>)
>>> torch.eye(5)
tensor([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
>>> torch.ones_like(inp)
tensor([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
>>> inp
tensor([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]], requires_grad=True)
```

But I didnt get how the tuts output is calculated. Can someone explain a bit of Jacobian matrix with calculations done in this example?

Answer (score 2):

We will go through the entire process: from computing the Jacobian to applying it to get the resulting gradient for this input. We're looking at the operation `f(x) = (x + 1)²`, in the simple scalar setting, we get `df/dx = 2(x + 1)` as complete derivative.

In the multi-dimensional setting, we have an input `x_ij`, and an output `y_mn`, indexed by `(i, j)`, and `(m, n)` respectively. The function mapping is defined as `y_mn = (x_mn + 1)²`.

First, we should look at the Jacobian itself, this corresponds to the tensor `J` containing all partial derivatives `J_ijmn = dy_mn/dx_ij`. From the expression of `y_mn` we can say that for all `i`, `j`, `m`, and `n`: `dy_mn/dx_ij = d(x_mn + 1)²/dx_ij` which is `0` if `m≠i` or `n≠j`. Else, *i.e.* `m=i` or `n=j`, we have that `d(x_mn + 1)²/dx_ij = d(x_ij + 1)²/dx_ij = 2(x_ij + 1)`.

As a result, `J_ijmn` can be simply defined as

```
         ↱ 2(x_ij + 1) if i=m, j=n
J_ijmn = 
         ↳ 0 else
```

From the rule chain the gradient of the output with respect to the input `x` is denoted as `dL/dx = dL/dy*dy/dx`. From a PyTorch perspective we have the following relationships:

- `x.grad = dL/dx`, shaped like `x`,
- `dL/dy` is the incoming gradient: the `gradient` argument in the [`backward`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.backward.html) function
- `dL/dx` is the Jacobian tensor described above.

As explained in the documentation, applying `backward` doesn't actually provide the Jacobian. It computes the chain rule product directly and stores the gradient (*i.e.* `dL/dx` inside `x.grad`).

In terms of shapes, the Jacobian multiplication `dL/dy*dy/dx = gradient*J` reduces itself to a tensor of the same shape as `x`.

The operation performed is defined by: `[dL/dx]_ij = ∑_mn([dL/dy]_ij * J_ijmn)`.

---

If we apply this to your example. We have `x = 1(i=j)` (where `1(k): (k == True) -> 1` is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)), essentially just the identity matrix.

We compute the Jacobian:

```
         ↱ 2(1(i=j) + 1) =  if i=m, j=n
J_ijmn = 
         ↳ 0 else
```

which becomes

```
         ↱ 2(1 + 1) = 4  if i=j=m=n
J_ijmn = → 2(0 + 1) = 2  if i=m, j=n, i≠j
         ↳ 0 else
```

---

For visualization purposes, we will stick with `x = torch.eye(2)`:

```
>>> f = lambda x: (x+1)**2
>>> J = A.jacobian(f, inp)
tensor([[[[4., 0.],
          [0., 0.]],

         [[0., 2.],
          [0., 0.]]],


        [[[0., 0.],
          [2., 0.]],

         [[0., 0.],
          [0., 4.]]]])
```

Then computing the matrix multiplication using [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html) (I won't go into details, look through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum), then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55894693/understanding-pytorch-einsum) for an in-depth overview of the EinSum summation operator):

```
>>> torch.einsum('ij,ijmn->mn', torch.ones_like(inp), J)
tensor([[4., 2.],
        [2., 4.]])
```

This matches what you get when back propagating from `out` with `torch.ones_like(inp)` as incoming gradient:

```
>>> out = f(inp)
>>> out.backward(torch.ones_like(inp))
>>> inp.grad
tensor([[4., 2.],
        [2., 4.]])
```

If you backpropagate twice (while retaining the graph of course) you end up computing the same operation which accumulating on the parameter's `grad` attribute. So, naturally, after two backward passes you have **twice** the gradient:

```
>>> out = f(inp)
>>> out.backward(torch.ones_like(inp), retain_graph=True)
>>> out.backward(torch.ones_like(inp))
>>> inp.grad
tensor([[8., 4.],
        [4., 8.]])
```

Those gradients will accumulate, you can reset them by calling the inplace function `zero_`: `inp.grad.zero_()`. From there if you backpropagate again you will stand with *one accumulate gradient* only.

In practice, you would register your parameters on an [optimizer](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html), from which you can call `zero_grad` enabling you to handle and reset all parameters in that collection in one go.

---

<sub>I have imported [`torch.autograd.functional`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html) as `A`</sub>