# Pixel operations in batches

Tags: python, computer-vision, pytorch, vectorization

I have a batch of depth images, shape -> [B, 1, H, W]. For each pixel in each image of the batch I need to perform:

`X = d * Kinverse @ [u, v, 1]   #therefore X is in R^3`
where d is float tensor[0;1] representing depth at pixel u,v; Kinverse is a constant 3X3 matrix and u, v refer to the pixel column and row respectively.

Is there some way I can vectorize the operation to obtain X(u+1,v), X(u,v) and X(u,v+1) for all the images in the batch.
I eventually need to take this cross product:
{X(u+1,v) - X(u,v)} x {X(u, v+1) - X(u,v)}

Thanks for the help!

Comment: so `d` is of shape `[B, 1, H, W]` ?

Comment: @Shai yes! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`torch.meshgrid`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.meshgrid.html#torch.meshgrid) to produce the `u` and `v` tensors. Once you have them, you can use [`torch.einsum`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55894780/1714410) to do the batched matrix multiplication with `Kinverse`.
Finally, you can use [`torch.cross`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cross.html#torch.cross) to compute the cross product:

```py
u, v = torch.meshgrid(*[torch.arange(s_, dtype=d.dtype, device=d.device) for s_ in d.shape[2:]])
# make a single 1x1xHxW for [u v 1] per pixel:
uv = torch.cat((u[None, None, ...], v[None, None, ...], torch.ones_like(u)[None, None, ...]), dim=1)
# compute X
X = d * torch.einsum('ij,bjhw->bihw',Kinverse,uv)
# the cross product
out = torch.cross(X[..., 1:, :-1] - X[..., :-1, :-1], X[..., :-1, 1:] - X[..., :-1, :-1], dim=1)
```