# Column Wise Dot-Product torch.einsum not matching torch.sum(torch.mul(), axis=0)

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I am trying to perform a dot product between the columns of two tensors. I am trying to do this in the most efficient way possible. However, my two methods are not matching up.

My first method using `torch.sum(torch.mul(a, b), axis=0)` gives me my expected results, `torch.einsum('ji, ji -> i', a, b)` (take from [Efficient method to compute the row-wise dot product of two square matrices of the same size in PyTorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69702937/efficient-method-to-compute-the-row-wise-dot-product-of-two-square-matrices-of-t)) does not. The reproducible code is below:

```
import torch
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
torch.manual_seed(0)

a = torch.randn(3,1, dtype=torch.float).to(device)
b = torch.randn(3,4, dtype=torch.float).to(device)

print(f"a : \n{a}\n")
print(f"b : \n{b}\n")
print(f"Expected:    {a[0,0]*b[0,0] + a[1,0]*b[1,0] + a[2,0]*b[2,0]}")

c = torch.sum(torch.mul(a, b), axis=0)
print(f"sum and mul: {c[0].item()}")

d = torch.einsum('ji, ji -> i', a, b)
print(f"einsum:      {d[0].item()}\n")

print(torch.eq(c,d))
```

The output is:
[image]

Notes:
On the CPU (all I did was remove the `.to(device)`) the last line `torch.eq(c,d)` is all true however, I need the tensors to be on the GPU.

Also for some seeds such as `torch.manual_seed(100)` the tensor are equal...

I feel like it has to be something with `einsum` because I can get my expected answer with other ways.

Comment: It seems like a numerical error. Try using `torch.double` if you want to reduce it.

Answer (score 0):

As highlighted by [@Hayoung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16115033/hayoung), this is due to a numerical error in the computation of your operation. Even with *double* as data type you will get different results. You may use [`torch.isclose`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.isclose.html) to compare tensor values.

```
>>> torch.isclose(c, d)
tensor([True, True, True, True], device='cuda:0')
```